# Using DataContract on ISerialized implemented class

Tags: .net, wcf

I have class A which has ISerializable implemented for custom serialization. Now i need to pass around this class A in WCF.

I want to use DataContractSerializer for WCF serialization not my custom serialization.

WCF would not allow it, it does not allow [DataContract] atribute if class has ISerializable implemented.

How can i use DataContractSerializer(For WCF) and ISerializer(For Persistance) on same class?

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but it does explain the "why?" part of it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5fdfc1d7-89f2-4f8b-a491-d9ac2cb0600c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in the comments, you cannot have both serialization methods.

If you:

- Place your classes in a separate dll.
- Reference the dll from both client
  and server projects.
- Remove the [DataContract] Attribute.

Then it should work, unless there is something special with respect to how the custom serialization is implemented.

Comment: Thanks,

I was under impression that datacontract and Iserialization uses different serializer but both are using same.

I have been using Iserialization implementation now.